# Fix Android Studio Corrupted Project Workspace Settings

Tags: android-studio

I had this problem for a while and was able to solve it myself.

If in opening your project in Android Studio and something similar to this error message pops up:

```
Cannot load settings from file (C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName\.idea\workspace.xml): Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Please correct the file content.
```

Answer (score 79):

It probably means your project workspace settings file is corrupted by whatever reason and Android Studio could not read it. Mine is probably because of BSOD, because Windows.

To solve the error, just delete the workspace.xml as specified in the error message. It is ok to delete it since you probably already lost all your custom workspace settings when the file got corrupted and you will never be able to save new workspace settings unless you fix the corrupted file. After deleting it, the next time you open your project in Android Studio, it will try to look for the workspace file, and if it can't find it, it will just create a new valid one.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Any idea how to fix this on a Mac?

Comment: Just to add, after deleting the workspce.xml . Kill Android studio and restart it. Otherwise it uses the old workspace.xml

Comment: instead of deleting and re-creating file, just leave the file content empty (make sure the file have utf8 encoding so Android Studio can read it) Android Studio will recreate the correct xml content file.

Comment: Same problem appeared on Windows 10 and Android Studio ver3.1. Deleting workspace.xml and restarting Studio, solved it.

Comment: I delete the whole .idea directory for it to work back.

Comment: Plz tell me where to find this `workspace.xml` file!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me I don't know why..!

Answer (score 49):

Step 1 :Exit Android Studio.

Step 2 :Delete `workspace.xml` file found in the `\ProjectName\.idea\` directory.

Step 3 :Run Android Studio again.

Comment: How is it better than Nico Dumdum's answer? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25985850/1617737

Comment: It doesn't really add anything but, yes, I suppose so.

Answer (score 16):

On a Mac, I found File > Invalidate Caches/Restart did the trick.

Comment: No—I think this is one of a number of possible fixes. I saw some of the other answers worked for other users.

Answer (score 12):

on a windows 8.1,  I found File > Invalidate Caches/Restart did the trick

Comment: this worked for me without deleting the xml file. thanks

Comment: Hey guys this worked for me on Window 7, Android Studio 3.6.3. I only did File > Invalidate Caches/Restart nothing else. Short and effective.

Answer (score 9):

I have encountered similar problem many times, and there just one thing that can be done to solve this.

Just delete **idea** folder.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to suggest restart Android studio **File > invalidate caches and restart... > invalidate caches and restart** option before deleting **workspace.xml**

if restarting android studio fail to solve your problem, kindly run **check disk** from disk properties because I notice that this error is raise due to **file indexing / file system error** or sometime **permission denied** by OS.

*Just Delete idea folder ..*

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Just delete .idea folder from project directory an re run android studio.
it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

in Terminal navigate to your project directory, and run these

```
rm -rf .idea
rm *.iml
```

then go into your app directory and do that same thing as above.

Finally, "File" -> "New" -> "Import", this should solve the corruption.

Comment: With AS 4.0 this is the only measure that worked.
In my case, removing the .idea/ directory was all that was required.
However, it meant re-adding words to the project dictionary, and re-installing signing certificates.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Android Studio 4.0 I solved this by:

1. Deleting `.idea` folder in the Project
2. Restart Android Studio

Done :)

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered similar problem many times, and there just one thing that can be done to solve this.

step 1 : delete the .xml files containing error, or cut and paste to some backup folder if you want to inspect that file later on. However, it's unlikely that you'd find anything.

step 2 : try to open android studio after having deleted those files, it must be running perfect. if it doesn't and still contains errors try 'invalidate catches and restart' option in file menu.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted the workspace.xml after closing the studio and started again.
It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since for me didn't worked to delete the file i just override the actual `workspace.xml` with the one i had on backup directory of my project. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Had Today the same Problem, but i found a "workspace.xml" with something like "**jpt_tmp**" at his end, in the same directory. After swaping the "tmp" once with the original, i got everything back to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many options but finally for windows 10,  File > Invalidate Caches/Restart worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problems depends on each situation. I was using Flutter in Android Studio and suddenly one day this problem occurred.

Just delete the `project_name.iml` in Flutter project and `project_name_android.iml` in android module.

For android projects simply delete `.iml` file in the project.

After deleting restart Android Studio and follow the steps as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a19xGVBeMM). It was of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for delay response, I also came across this scenario, so tried to resolve it using many way available on internet which include

1. invalidate cache and restart
2. restart android studio
3. deleting *.iml file
4. restart system

The only solution worked for me is, I export my project into zip format and then I open it from there. The project open and build successfully without any problem.

I hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was iml file which was corrupted, so i deleted it, restarted android studio,
pasted the same file as it was before, restarted android studio and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

A gradle sync did the trick for me.

Just press the button from the toolbar named "sync project with gradle files". The icon is an elephant with a little blue arrow.

If it still does not work, try deleting the .idea folder first, before syncing the gradle files again.