# blank android studio "can't load settings from file workspace.xml"

Tags: android, android-studio

When i open android studio it shows me blank screen like i don't have any projects with a yellow message at the top corner that says "can't load setting from file workspace.xml..."

After i tried to delete the workspace.xml file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985849/fix-android-studio-corrupted-project-workspace-settings) and open android studio again the message didn't appear but it was still without any projects. Yesterday everything worked fine and i can still see my project data on the windows explorer. Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

go to your user folder

> [SYSDRIVE]:\Users[your username] (ex. C:\Users\aman)

In this folder there should be a folder called **.AndroidStudioBeta** or **.AndroidStudio** (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

this will solve your problem.