# Corrupted project workspace settings in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This message appears when I open Android Studio project.

> Cannot load settings from file
>   (C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\"AndroidStudioProjectName".idea\workspace.xml):
>   Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Please correct the
>   file content.

Comment: Which solution did you try? Generally, you can solve this by just deleting workspace.xml and reopening the project. Of course: the content (if it contained specific information) will be lost (but is obviously corrupted anyway).

Comment: Please include a link to the similar question that you already tried the solutions to.

Comment: I tried to delete workspace.xml and reopen a project, but there is no java class at all...just xml stuff. Here is a link for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985849/fix-android-studio-corrupted-project-workspace-settings

Comment: Have you solved  this (without rebuilding the whole damn pc)?

Comment: Take a look at linked answer in comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the workspace file, and then don't open the project but import it. In the launcher, click on Import project and give it the projects path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Same result again...I can open project but there are just resources without code(java class is empty). I guess I need to start all over again with this project :(

Comment: If you manually (with windows explorer) go into your project/app/src/main/yourPackage/YourJavaClass (and open it with notepad), is it empty too or do you see the code?

Comment: So your standard texteditor (windows: notepad.exe) shows the file as empty?

How big does your explorer say it is? If it's 0Byte, your class actually is empty.

Comment: When I open it in with notepad.exe there is nothing, but it says it is 5.68KB.

Comment: Wow completely out of ideas why/how this could happen. Copy+paste the file somewhere else (desktop?) and see what it says? Maybe go to its properties and try to get a former version, if you have that feature enabled.

Comment: Hmm...I really don't know what happened. I will try something tomorrow. Thanks for your support. I found backup of that project but there are some parts of the code missing because that backup is about one month old.