# My android studio does not load my project with an error

Tags: android, eclipse, settings

i worked on a project on android studio and then one day when i working with it, my windows got error and i forced to reset my window. 
next time when i back to android studio, my recent project can,t load and I occurred with this error message:

> Load Settings
>
> Cannot load settings from file 'D:\Shajary\project\AndroidStudioProjects\Almizan2.idea\gradle.xml': content truncated
>               File content will be recreated

i search net for this error. but they can not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means your project workspace settings file is corrupted by whatever reason and Android Studio could not read it. Mine is probably because of BSOD, because Windows.

To solve the error, just delete the workspace.xml as specified in the error message. It is ok to delete it since you probably already lost all your custom workspace settings when the file got corrupted and you will never be able to save new workspace settings unless you fix the corrupted file. After deleting it, the next time you open your project in Android Studio, it will try to look for the workspace file, and if it can't find it, it will just create a new valid one.

I hope this helps! :)

ans just copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985849/fix-android-studio-corrupted-project-workspace-settings)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but my problem not solved. after do these, android studio suggest to me to import gradle project and when i try to import, android studio cant import.